# WordPress in other languages

Tags: wordpress, installation, multilingual

I would like to set WordPress theme to be in a language other than English, but I would like to keep the control panel of WordPress in English. How do I accomplish that?

Changing `define('WPLANG', '');` in **wp-config.php** would not help, as it will change the language for the control panel as well.

I am not interested in a plugin, all I need is set the language for the theme, but not the control panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example, front end will be Dutch, back end default English:

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin' ) === false ) :
    define( 'WPLANG', 'nl_NL' );
else :
    define( 'WPLANG', '' );
endif;
```

---

### UPDATE

WordPress 4.0 deprecated the `WPLANG` constant ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.0#Deprecated_2)). The site language is set from the admin panel: *Settings -> General -> Site Language*.

Developers can now modify the locale by defining the `$locale` global in `wp-config.php`, ...

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin' ) === false ) :
    $locale = 'nl_NL';
else :
    $locale = 'en_US';
endif;
```

... or with the `locale` filter:

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'so16425245_filter_locale', 0, 1 );
function so16425245_filter_locale( $locale )
{
    if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/' ) !== false )
        return 'en_US';

    return 'nl_NL';
}
```

See also Greeso's answer with regard to admin AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out.

Comment: Updated for WP 4.0 and higher

Comment: I am not sure why you removed my update about AJAX, anyway, I added it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Greeso, I restored part of your edit, because it's a useful approach for some cases, and referenced your additional answer (which still uses `WP_LANG` btw) regarding AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by 'diggy' is great, and works most of the time. However it will not work in one situation:

If you are using AJAX within WordPress, then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will contain `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` even if you are at the site root (for example if you go to www.your-site.com, then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` if you are using AJAX in that root page).

Therefore, to work around this issue, you should modify the condition inspection to be as follows:

```
if ( ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin' ) === false ) || (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) !== false) ) :
    define( 'WPLANG', 'nl_NL' );
else :
    define( 'WPLANG', '' );
endif;
```

---

### Update

For 4.0 and up, use the following

```
if ( ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin' ) === false ) || (strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) !== false) ) :
    $locale = 'nl_NL';
else :
    $locale = 'en_US';
endif;
```